# Which Logitech app do I need to download for my mouse?

Tags: drivers, logitech-mouse

I have a simple M510 Logitech Wireless mouse.  I'm having some problems with the inconsistency in its functionality, so before you tell me to just use the default Windows drivers: I'd love to do that but some things are not working for me, so I want to *try* using the official vendor drivers...

Here is my problem:  I go to the download screen for the M510 mouse on Logitech.com, and I'm presented with three downloads:

1. **Logitech Setpoint**
   "Setpoint lets you customize your mouse, keyboard, touchpad and numberpad settings in Windows."
   OK, software that lets me customize my device sounds like it would need drivers to interact with the device.  Plus, I think in the past I have installed Setpoint before when I wanted drivers for my Logitech products.
2. **Logitech Options**
   "Logitech Options software lets you customize your device settings."
   Um, that sounds like the same thing as Setpoint.  How do I differentiate between these two options?
3. **Logitech Unifying Software**
   OK, I know that the Mouse communicates with the computer through a USB "Unifying" Wireless receiver.  So, that sounds like it could also have a driver.

I want to install the official drivers for this mouse, but I certainly don't want to have to install ***three*** pieces of software for a plain-old Wireless mouse.

Which of these is the right option?

Comment: I would start with the Logitech Options software *if* you want to use the "Back/Forward buttons, side-to-side scrolling and zoom". If you want to use more than one Logitech device on the Unifying wireless receiver then you will need the Unifying software. If you had a Logitech keyboard, you would need the SetPoint sotfware if you wanted to use custom features of that keyboard. The "Options" s/w might download SetPoint anyway. They don't make it simple.

Comment: For anyone looking at Setpoint versus Options specifically: **it depends on the mouse**. Older models require Setpoint, newer models need Options. Short of looking at the original packaging, you'll only find out by trying. I'm using two at the same time with a few laptops and need both applications installed.

Comment: Its been long, but in case any one still thinking the same, it all depends on how old your your device is. Also take a look at the last modified date of these software, [Logitech Unifying Software: Last Update: 2010-03-30, SetPoint: 2021-09-13, Logitech Options:2022-01-07]. So it looks like 'Options' is the latest. Ref: https://support.logi.com/hc/en-ca/articles/360024701174--Downloads-Wireless-Mouse-M510

Comment: I've just installed the new Logi Options+, and when I click on the mouse settings it automatically opens the old Setpoint app. So, they are connected.

Answer (score 3):

It says on the official Logitech site for the mouse: (http://www.logitech.com/en-us/product/wireless-mouse-m510)

> *Requires Logitech® Options™ software.*

Comment: Please read [How to reference material written by others](http://superuser.com/help/referencing). 
You should block quote text that has been written by some else. See [Markdown help](https://superuser.com/editing-help).
I've fixed it for you this time, but please pay attention to this in future.

Comment: That doesn't really answer my question.  The page says that that software is necessary for specific functions listed in the product description, but not necessarily that it contains the basic drivers.  For all I know, **Setpoint** could contain the basic drivers, and then **Options** is required as an additional install to enable advanced features.  It seems improbable but I've seen worse.  The crux of my issue is that the three download options provided by Logitech seem to have overlapping functionality and are not clearly distinguishable in terms of purpose.

Comment: What drivers are currently running for your mouse?

Comment: You might want to try updating the driver in Device Manager to see if that will easily fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

When Logitech started using the unified receiver, the existing SetPoint software became largely incompatible and lost both the mouse and battery tabs. This forced users to also download the options software and sometimes even the Unified250 software all in an effort to restore the full functionality of the new unified devices. Sometimes this worked and sometimes not.
When I switched from my failing MX620 mouse to my new M510 mouse, here is the **partial** fix I used on **Windows XP** because the options software won't install on XP. I completely uninstalled the SetPoint and Unified250 software. I replugged the Unified USB receiver for the M510 mouse. The mouse was then working with only the default button settings (L-click, R-click, Vertical Wheel scroll, Forward and Back buttons, Wheel Click search). I then downloaded X-Mouse Button Control v2.17 (latest supports all 32bit (x86) and 64bit (x64) editions of Windows from Windows XP to 10, including Windows Server editions). Installed 5.3 MB in 31 files. I can now redefine all buttons except left and right wheel tilt. I never used it anyway. I can also live without knowing the remaining battery power.
I don't what OS you're using but I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that setpoint is an older version of options basically. Check the logitech page on your device for more info on which driver it uses. That being said, it’s optional. If you don’t need to use it you don’t need to download it.

Answer (score 0):

Having grappled with this issue for more than a year, and having searched for the answer to this question for the better part of the last hour, the answer I am providing is both... or neither. [eye roll] I have an MX Ergo and an  M570 that I use on the same Windows 10 Pro editing rig (I travel with the Ergo, so sometimes it's not with me when I'm at my main machine).  I need the tiny index finger buttons mapped to "forward/back" on my video editing timeline.  The MX Ergo only works with Logitech Options, and that's where I set the functionality for those buttons.  I can use Logitech Options "unifying receiver" functionality to get the computer to *recognize* my M570 (via the unifying receive dongle), but to assign any *functionality* to the extra buttons and wheel, I have to install Setpoint, because the M570 does not show up as a "registered device" in Logitech Options.  It's not like the M570 is outdated.  Logitech still manufactures and sells it, so why in the world isn't it supported in Logitech Options?!  If you don't need to assign specific button functionality, you actually don't need to install *either* Logitech Options or Logitech Setpoint.  If you aren't using Bluetooth (MX Ergo) and are using the unifying receiver dongle, you can install a *third* Logitech program who's only functionality is recognizing unifying receiver devices, and then you can use Windows Mouse Settings to alter pointer speed, reverse buttons, etc.